# SpringBoot bootBuildImage with docker-compose build?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, docker-image

Spring Boot recommends using it's Maven/Gradle plugins to build a Docker image (actually, an OCI image which is similar). From https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker, with Gradle, you run:

```bash
gradle bootBuildImage --imageName=myorg/myapp
```

docker-compose lets you specify a build config with a Dockerfile like this:

```yaml
  backend:
    image: example/database
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: ../backend.Dockerfile
```

Is there any way for a docker-compose build to reference the Spring Boot `gradle bootBuildImage` step instead of a Dockerfile?

I can build a Spring Booth image with `gradle bootBuildImage`

I can configure a more traditional Dockerfile based image build in docker-compose with `build.dockerfile`.

Is there any way to specify the Spring Boot image build in a docker-compose configuration?